# What Forms do coal and crude oil fall under?

Tags: ars-magica-5

In Ars Magica 5, what Forms would be suitable for working with coal? My initial assumption would be Terram, but I can see an argument for requiring Herbam as a prerequisite.

Similarly, what Form includes crude oil (or its derivatives, like petroleum, kerosene or tar)? Aquam? Terram? Herbam? Something else?

Comment: energiae purae.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the terms of the period that Ars Magica evokes, all these substances come out of the ground, so they're Terram.